Error: LateInitializationError: Field '_makeYogaStyle' has not been initialized
while using rive package in flutter I got an  Error: LateInitializationError: Field '_makeYogaStyle' has not been initialized. The error message suggests an internal issue within the Rive library: "_makeYogaStyle" hasn't been initialized. This likely indicates a bug within the library's layout engine.
Encountering a LateInitializationError with the message "Field '_makeYogaStyle' has not been initialized."

If _makeYogaStyle isn't any variable in your code, I recommend filling an issue on the rive repository. You also could try to use an press an older version of rive to see if it's happening there too, helping them to locate the problem

Can you share the code where this issue is coming from?

I don't have a good kowing of Rive animations, but have you tryed declaring a _makeYogaStyle var in your code? and inspect that var if error dissipear?

That error is causing from the rive animation package
